# Given $A \subseteq X$ we can have $\sup A < \inf A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

For some poset $(X,<)$ with a global max $\top$ and min $\bot$ with $\bot < \top$, and a subset $A = \varnothing$, we'd have $\sup \varnothing = \bot$ and $\inf \varnothing = \top$, right? So $\sup \varnothing < \inf \varnothing$.

This just seemed initially counter-intuitive so I want to make sure I'm interpreting this correctly.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: For an intuition for this, I always imagine the real numbers, the supremum at the bottom, the infimum at the top, and when you start "adding numbers" to the set that you are taking the inf and sup, the supremum moves above all the numbers and the infimum moves below. So if there are no numbers in the set the inf should initially be at the top and the supremum at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, $\sup \varnothing = \bot$ and $\inf \varnothing = \top$. The reason for this seemingly counterintuitive behavior is to make properties like $\sup (A \cup B) = \sup \{ \sup A, \sup B \}$ work out, without having to worry about $\varnothing$ as a special case. I.e., $\sup \varnothing = \bot$ because $\bot$ is the neutral element w.r.t. $\sup$, very much the same reason why $\sum_{i \in \varnothing} a_i = 0$ and $\prod_{i \in \varnothing} a_i = 1$.

Comment: Actually the reason is just a byproduct of a definition of $\sup$ and $\inf$.

Comment: Sure, but from the formulation of the question, I guess the OP is quite well-aware of the definitions and how that means $\sup \varnothing = \bot$. I just wanted to point out that this is quite reasonable (and convenient) to happen. (Which is of course why the definition is what it is.)